# How do I tell Windows to delete certain files when it restarts / reboots?

Tags: uninstall

When I uninstall something, often the uninstaller would say, "so-and-so files will be deleted when you restart".  Naively I presume the uninstaller leaves Windows instructions somewhere to do this.

How do I manually add files to this list of files to be deleted? (Also, will this trick work with what versions of windows?)  And, can I use the trick for folders?

This has nothing to do with DeepFreeze, Windows SteadyState, Norton GoBack or Norton Ghost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has a "SysInternals" tool to do this, [MoveFile](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897556). If you specify `""` as the destination, it will not be moved but deleted. Works on all recent Windows versions (Microsoft refuses to acknowledge Windows 2000's existance, but it works there too).

Comment: Ah there! Thanks! Question, @MSalters: Instead of downloading and running MoveFile.exe can I just add lines to the HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\PendingFileRenameOperations registry entry instead? (Gonna try it now....)

Comment: I note that this also works for deleting given empty folders. Alright.

Comment: @WilliamC: If you want to do it programatically, the proper way is to call `MoveFileEx`. However, the key _is_ documented, so you could. To prevent race conditions, when modifying the key you'll have to do so in a transaction (which requires Vista or later - hence te advice to use `MoveFileEx`)

Answer (score 0):

BusyDelete (BDel) will do it for you:
http://users.csc.calpoly.edu/~bfriesen/software/console.shtml